# Compilation errors in MSVC

Tags: c++

I'm usually a g++ user. And I loved it for it's simplicity, but I'm trying to test compiling a `native` executable because usually I create a static which is really heavy in size. But I'm having some errors.

One on this line : `return in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

```
warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
file.cpp(95): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
file.cpp(95): error C2144: syntax error: 'unknown-type' should be preceded by ')'
file.cpp(95): error C2144: syntax error: 'unknown-type' should be preceded by ';'
file.cpp(95): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

and here

```
DWORD mxpath = MAX_PATH;
            char ld[mxpath];
```

```
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
sas.cpp(76): note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
sas.cpp(76): note: see usage of 'mxpath'
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong as this code works with g++ without any errors. I'm new to msvc and I wanted to see if it is better than compiling a g++ static.

Why are those errors coming?

Comment: Define `NOMINMAX` in project settings, or before including `windows.h`. Windows headers define `min` and `max` as macros, for certain historical reasons; `NOMINMAX` suppresses that.

Comment: Make it `char ld[MAX_PATH]`. It's OK to use a constant as array bound, but not a variable (even if just initialized to that constant).

Comment: Without a `const` on `mxpath` you are attempting to create a VLA which VC doesn’t support.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I defined that after I saw a stackoverflow question. That just flooded me with a ton of errors! About the ld, I will try that.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I see.

Comment: What kind of errors? Show the first one.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Here ``c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\GdiplusTypes.h(479): error C3861: 'min': identifier not found`` This error is 10 for each file, I have 4.

Comment: Hmm, that's tricky. I guess you could `#include <algoithm> using std::min; using std::max;` before including GDI+ headers.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik After doing that, The error is now this. ``c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\GdiplusTypes.h(479): error C3861: 'min': identifier not found
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\GdiplusTypes.h(480): error C3861: 'min': identifier not found``

Comment: What do you mean, "now is this"? You make it sound like something's changed, but that's the same error you cited in the previous comment.

Comment: Sorry that was a Grammar mistake. I mean, The error is still the same.